# Plugin to request combined shipping rate before processing payment

Tags: shipping, plugin

I'm looking for a plugin where the buyer can add all of the items into their cart and request a manual combined shipping rate before processing their payment. I need to be able to manually adjust the shipping rate, yet have the order marked as "pending" so that way the buyer's items aren't sold to someone else in the process.

Comment: What do you mean by 'manual combined shipping rate'? Combination of what? More details would be helpful.

Comment: Because I am a small business, I need to manually calculate the total combined shipping rate depending on the specific combined item weight and sizes of items. I can't have flat rate shipping or a shipping estimate, I want to be able to offer the exact shipping cost

Answer (score 0):

If you have a FedEx, USPS, DHL or UPS account enter your credentials in `System->Configuration->Shipping Method` and you will get a real quote based on weight. That's the normal behavior, you don't need a plugin.

You can see the configuration instructions here : http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#shipping/online-rates.html%3FTocPath%3DShipping%7CBasic%2520Shipping%2520Methods%7C_____5

Comment: I forgot to mention that my business and warehouse ships from Asia, so unfortunately this isnt a option.

Comment: Which shipping companies do you use?

Comment: I use Hong Kong post. I would like to setup automatic weight calculation but  I use several packing material such poly bag and box etc, postage varies based on the item and packing material configuration, therefor i need to be able to manually input the combined shipping cost.

Comment: Ah. So, basically, you want to pause the order, with status pending. Then you will manually determine the shipping costs and input them in the admin area, then the customer will come back and pay, releasing the order to move through the process. Right?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I need. But I need the order to appear as "pending" or remove the items from available stock.

Comment: That's going to be difficult - at that point the order is already placed, so technically you will be editing an order, which causes the original order to be deleted and a new order to be created, with -1 appended to it's order number. i.e. Order # 145000004-1.

Comment: If that's not a concern, you could force the order to stop at pending, then add a line item to the order for the shipping charge. Rename your free shipping method to "Get Shipping Quote" or something,  which will have a 0.00 price. Then, stop the order at pending. Get the quote, then edit the order, adding the shipping cost as a line item with a custom price. You will get a "-1" on the order number, but if you can live with that then this may be the easiest method.

Comment: The order would actually be cancelled, then a new one created. I wrote "deleted" in my earlier comment.